# Is there a way to find if one or more events within a recurring series has been deleted?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm using the following code to check if there are cancelled events in a Google Calendar. It works fine for regular, non-recurring events. However, I run into issue when the user has deleted a single event in a recurring event series.

```
  function checkForCancelledEvents(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data Source");
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);

  //sort by date added
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,2,lastRow, 5)
  var values = range.getValues();
  //in the array the 3 position is the eventId, the 4 position is the calendar ID, I'm putting more into the array since I was playing around with also using the start date or time to solve the problem

  //loop through all using Calendar.Events.get
  for (i=1;i<values.length;i++) {
    var splitEventID = values[i][3].toString().split("@")[0] //remove the calendarID from the eventID

    if (Calendar.Events.get(values[i][4],splitEventID).status === "cancelled") {
      //the below clears the content of the row that contains the cancelled events
      //the range has to start at i + 1 since the values include the header row, but the for loop starts at 1 instead of 0 to prevent the API from calling with data from header row (which produces an error). So i + 1 gives the accurate row number for which the cancelled event lives
      var clearRange = sheet.getRange(i + 1,1,1,7) 
      clearRange.clearContent()
    } else {
      //Logger.log("this is NOT cancelled")
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is that recurring events all contain the same eventID and calendarID. They have the same iCalUID as well. Recurring events do have a different `id` but non-recurring events don't have the same `id` format. I tried to use Calendar.event.list and add the `timeMin` of each event within the recurring series, however the event was still listed as `confirmed` even though it was deleted.
Is there a way to find if a single event within a recurring series has been deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From `Is there a way to find if a single event within a recurring series has been deleted?`, you want to know whether even one of the events from the recurring events is removed using Google Apps Script.

In this case, I thought that when the method of "Events: instances" is used, your goal might be able to be achieved. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Calendar API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
var calendarId = "###"; // Please set the calendar ID.
var eventId = "###"; // Please set the event ID.

var ar = [];
var pageToken = "";
do {
  var res = Calendar.Events.instances(calendarId, eventId, {maxResults: 2500, showDeleted: true, pageToken});
  if (res.items.length > 0) ar = [...ar, ...res.items.filter(({status}) => status == "cancelled")];
  pageToken = res.nextPageToken;
} while (pageToken);
if (ar.length > 0) {
  // When "ar" has the values, the events are deleted from the recurring events.

  // do something.

}
```

- In the above script, you can see the information of the deleted events at `ar`.

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your actual situation.

#### Reference:

- [Events: instances](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/instances)

Comment: Thank you! That appears to work well. Can you tell me what the three dots do in this line `ar = [...ar,`? I've been trying to access the dateTime of the cancelled event. Any help on that?

Comment: Disregard the question in my comment. I figured it out using `Logger.log(ar[0]["start"]["dateTime"])`

Comment: @Craig.Pearce Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.